# TYPO3 7.6. Lightbox for the extension calendarize

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I try to build the link for a lightbox in my template of the extension calendarize.
The smaller images are correct, but in my lightbox wrong images are shown. 
The title, the description ... are fine

```
        <f:for each="{event.images}" as="image" iteration="i">
            <a href="{f:uri.image(src:image.uid)}" 
               class="lightbox" rel="lightbox[{image.uid}]" 
               title="{image.originalResource.title}" 
               alt="{image.originalResource.alternative}">
                <f:image src="{image.uid}" treatIdAsReference="1" 
                         alt="{image.originalResource.title}" 
                         maxWidth="200" 
                         class="img-rounded"/>
            </a>
            <figcaption>{image.originalResource.title}</figcaption>
        </f:for>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. I had to add

```
treatIdAsReference:1
```

to get

```
<a href="{f:uri.image(src:image.uid treatIdAsReference:1)}"
```